# Find "next" nearest node using OSMNx

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx

I have been using OSMNx for several projects where I'm matching recorded GPS traces to the OSM network.

Usually matching to the nearest node/edge gets me what I'm after, but I've come across a few situations (because the GPS has drifted badly) where the nearest node is NOT what I'm after.

I have read the documentation but I can't see any way to use `osmnx.nearest_nodes()` to get anything other than the single closest node. So I'm trying to figure out a way to get the next nearest node to a given lat/lon point.

I'm aware I can take the lat/lon point, buffer that to a polygon, and then use `osmnx.graph_from_polygon()`. But that requires me to make some estimate of the buffer distance which will inevitably be too big (resulting in too many nodes to process) or too small (resulting in not reaching the next closest node).

Comment: If you get a "false" nearest node, you could temporarily remove it from the graph, redo the nearest node search, then add it back to the graph.

Comment: Or you could use a scipy k-d tree and search for k=2 nodes in your own function, perhaps.

Comment: How complex is it to remove and replace a node? It's a thought that I had, but not at all sure how to achieve that. Could you provide an example?

Comment: I'll have a look into the scipy k-d option. Is that what `nearest_nodes()` is using?

Comment: I ended up solving this by just reworking the `nearest_nodes()` function as suggested by @gboeing. Because the function builds a GeoDataFrame from the submitted network, it's easy to "drop" nodes and no need to replace them as it does not affect the original network.